# Retrieving bytes from string representation of bytes in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

The following snippet works perfectly in outputting the correct UTF8 character representation:

```
a = b"Tenemos la Soluci\xc3\xb3n"
a.decode('utf8')
'Tenemos la Solución' # correct output
```

But in my use-case the actual bytes are stored as a string in Database. In that case how do i retrieve the output with correct UTF8 representation ?

```
a = "Tenemos la Soluci\xc3\xb3n" # retrieved from Database
b = bytes(a, 'utf8')
b.decode('utf8')
'Tenemos la SoluciÃ³n' # incorrect output
```

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), and it occurs when, for example, UTF-8-encoded text is stored in a database configured for ISO-8859-1 or similar encoding.  `latin1` is a 1:1 mapping of Unicode code points to equivalent bytes, assuming the Unicode string only contains U+0000 to U+00FF, and can be used to reverse the problem:

```
>>> a = "Tenemos la Soluci\xc3\xb3n" # retrieved from Database
>>> a.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'Tenemos la Solución'
```